# Help needed in choosing video production device for use with Matterhorn Capture Agent

Tags: video, streaming, video-capture

In our institution we need to record every class hours and upload it to our Matterhorn server with schedule recording, so i need a good video capture card which need to support a fixed camera and input device for mic and projector and a VGA option, If i'am i scheduled for a class it will automatically record the content and send to Matterhorn server and it will produce the video to other user interface to get watch could any one there to help me out to find a good capture card, asking here because you experts are in video production and you all sure know which card will provide the above requirements.   Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

One of the best resources you will find for this is probably the Matterhorn documentation itself. The [Capture Agent Hardware page](https://opencast.jira.com/wiki/display/MHDOC/Capture+Agent+Hardware) has samples of hardware that was used at a number of schools that have implemented capture agents for Matterhorn.  It appears that the Epiphan VGA2USB is the near universal standard for VGA capture.  There seems to be a wider range of video capture devices.

Personally, I'd probably take a look at seeing if the Black Magic Intensity or Matrox MXO2 works with the capture agent, but there are also other listed devices there such as capture devices from Hauppauge or Bluecherry which have actually been used successfully already.

Comment: Yes i have seen the capture agent hardware from Matterhorn, but it seems to be some old more than 2 years, so what i need to be up-to-date with any other compatible cards. at first we need to test before deploying in real environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AJ Henderson for Bluecherry, very cheaper than other brand let you know in future if any help needed for me.